# Is this algebraic identity obvious? $\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j\neq i} {\lambda_j\over \lambda_j-\lambda_i}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, products

If $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ are distinct positive real numbers, then 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j\neq i} {\lambda_j\over \lambda_j-\lambda_i}=1.$$
This identity follows from a probability calculation that you can find at the 
top of page 311 in the 10th edition of *Introduction to Probability Models* by Sheldon Ross.

Is there a slick or obvious explanation for this identity?

This  question is sort of similar to [my previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/is-this-a-known-algebraic-identity); clearly algebra is not my strong suit!

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241235/proof-of-sum-nolimits-i-1n-prod-nolimits-substackj-1-j-ne-i

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's the Lagrange interpolation polynomial for the constant function $1$ evaluated at $0$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n 1 \prod_{j\neq i} {{\lambda_j-0}\over \lambda_j-\lambda_i}=1$$

In general, you have that the polynomial below interpolates the data points $(\lambda_i,y_i$):
$$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \prod_{j\neq i} {{\lambda_j-x}\over \lambda_j-\lambda_i}$$

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I guess to rephrase: if $P(x) = \sum \prod (x-\lambda_j)/(\lambda_i - \lambda_j)$, then we can easily see that $P(\lambda_i) = 1$. Since $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, it is identically $1$. What we have here is $P(0)$.