# How to proof the following identity: $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \prod_{j=0\\j\neq k}^{n} \frac{t_k}{t_k-t_j} =1$

Tags: polynomials, summation

I've been trying to solve the determinant of the Vandermonde-matrix by using Laplace's formula on it (without transforming the matrix first).

It worked out quite well, I could almost instantly factor out the result that I was supposed to get, however not without the weird factor
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \prod_{j=0\\j\neq k}^{n} \frac{t_k}{t_k-t_j}
$$

For the formula to hold, the factor has to be equal to $1$, and I've tried it for small $n$, however I'm not seeing why exactly this identity has to hold.

Therefore:
Why does the identity
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \prod_{j=0\\j\neq k}^{n} \frac{t_k}{t_k-t_j} = 1
$$
hold for abitrary $t_i\in\mathbb C$?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/241235/42969.

Comment: @MartinR How did you find this? Now that I've realized that the search engine has its limits (before it almost always magically found what I was looking for), I've looked up a few ways, but none of it could find that result (it has different names for the variables + it's only via lagrange-polynomials related to the Vandermonde-matrix)

Comment: With [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%5Cprod_%7Bj%3D0%5C%5Cj%5Cneq%20k%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bt_k%7D%7Bt_k-t_j%7D%20%3D1%24&p=1). See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978/42969.