# three independent exponential random variables, find P(X<Y<Z), intuition

Tags: probability-theory

The question has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81181/probability-about-three-independent-exponential-random-variables?answertab=votes#tab-top).

There are three independent exponential variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ with parameter $\lambda$, $\mu$ and $\eta$. Find $P(X<Y<Z)$.

Part of the solution is that the event $X<Y<Z$ can be split into two independent events $X<min\{Y,Z\}$ and $Y<Z$.

My initial intuition was that the first of the two resulting events should be $X<Y$ instead. And I'm still having trouble to understand why this is incorrect.

Can someone point out why using $X<Y$ instead of $X<min\{Y,Z\}$ is wrong?

Comment: Using $X < Y$ rather than $X < \min\{Y, Z\}$ is wrong because $X< Y$ is not independent of $Y < Z$, so you cannot continue the argument.

Comment: Thank you! this helped a lot.